# Stored procedure with recursive call using mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, recursion

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5aNM.png)[get legside from binary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJvWh.png)

I have tried using stored procedure with recursive call. i need to display relevant name based on emp_name based on leg1

but it showing error like #1414 - OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine sample.getVolume is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

Here is my code,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getVolume( IN param_name VARCHAR(255), OUT result VARCHAR(255 ))
BEGIN 
SELECT val INTO result FROM employee WHERE emp_name = param_name ;
IF result IS NULL THEN
select result;
ELSE     
CALL getVolume(result, '');
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;



SET @@GLOBAL.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
SET @@session.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255; 
call getVolume('new', @result);
select @result;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of @Shadow is correct. Here a practical example that can help you:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employee`//
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getVolume`//

CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `emp_name` VARCHAR(255),
  `val` VARCHAR(255)
)//

INSERT INTO `employee` (`emp_name`, `val`)
VALUES
('demo', 'new'),
('new', 'd.new'),
('d.new', 'view'),
('view', 'hello'),
('hello', NULL)
//

CREATE PROCEDURE `getVolume`(
  IN `param_name` VARCHAR(255),
  OUT `result` VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE `next_param_name` VARCHAR(255);
  SELECT `val` INTO `next_param_name`
  FROM `employee`
  WHERE `emp_name` = `param_name`;

  IF `next_param_name` IS NULL THEN
    SET `result` := `param_name`;
  ELSE
    -- CALL `getVolume`(`result`, '');
    CALL `getVolume`(`next_param_name`, `result`);
    -- SET `result` := CONCAT(`param_name`, ',', IFNULL(`result`, ''));
  END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7292/2)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks wchiquito . Its working in minimum record. but if i used this SP in max no.of record(I have 4200 Records). It shows the error as "#1456 - Recursive limit 255 (as set by the max_sp_recursion_depth variable) was exceeded for routine getFinal ". Please see my updated question and guide to fix it.

Comment: @nagoormeeran: The maximum value of the variable `max_sp_recursion_depth` is: 255. See [5.1.4 Server System Variables (max_sp_recursion_depth)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_sp_recursion_depth).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you call getResult() within getresult, you pass an empty string **constant** as a parameter:

```
CALL getVolume(result, '');
```

Declare a variable instead and pass that as a parameter. After the getVolume call do not forget to concatenate what is returned by getVolume to the result variable with a separator character. Are you sure that 255 characters will be enough to hold all values?