# How to chain a series of numbers together in a MySQL DB with two columns defining the series connections?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL DB that defines series of numbers within sets as such:

```
set   item1    item2
1     1        2
1     2        3
1     3        4
1     4        5
1     5        6
```

I want to write a query (or queries) that returns to me the fact that set 1 is a series of numbers that spans from 1 to 6. Is this possible?

Please note that the real DB I'm dealing with contains hundreds of sets and that each set can contain a series of items that can be somewhat long as well (up to 50 items per set, I'm guessing). Also, I'm not totally sure, but the DB might also have cases where the series of numbers split. Using the example above, there may be instances like the following:

```
set   item1    item2
1     1        2
1     2        3
1     3        4
1     4        5
1     5        6
1     3        7
1     7        8
1     8        9
```

In which case, I'd want to know that set 1 has two series of numbers: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and `[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]`. Is this possible with hopefully one query (or if necessary, multiple queries)?

---

**Edit**: Please note that I used the numbers 1-9 in sequential order to make the question easier to understand. The real data is much more mixed up and not that orderly.

Comment: The second problem is a whole order of difficulty beyond the first one. There's no way here of knowing whether 7,8 belongs to series A or series B. (I don't even understand the logic of series B)

Comment: The two series split at `3`, that's all. Think of it like a fork in the road. I think it makes perfect sense given the data set, but I do admit that it's maybe impossible to handle with one (or maybe even multiple) MySQL calls alone. I may have to get PHP, etc. involved in this.

Comment: The real problem is clearly an order of magnitude more complex than even the second problem, so I'm uncertain what help we might be able to provide

Comment: You're very likely right, Strawberry. I wasn't even asking the question with the expectation that MySQL alone could solve my problem. I just thought I'd ask and see if there was some way to do it that I hadn't thought of. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are aware, MySQL cannot handle recursion 'out-of-the-box', so options include:

1. writing a stored procedure
2. switching from an adjacency list to an alternative model (e.g. nested set)
3. joining the table to itself as often as could be required
4. handling the recursion in application level code (e.g. a bit of PHP)

Here is an example using option 3, but it could be easily adapted to suit option 4...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    family_id INT NOT NULL,
    item_id INT NOT NULL,
    parent_id INT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(family_id, item_id)
);

INSERT INTO my_table 
VALUES (101, 1, null), (101, 2, 1), (101, 3, 2), (101, 4, 3),
       (101, 5, 4), (101, 6, 5), (101, 7, 3), (101, 8, 7), (101, 9, 8);

SELECT CONCAT_WS(','
     , a.item_id 
     , b.item_id
     , c.item_id
     , d.item_id
     , e.item_id
     , f.item_id 
     , g.item_id
     , h.item_id
     , i.item_id
     ) series
FROM 
    my_table a
LEFT JOIN 
    my_table b ON b.parent_id = a.item_id AND b.family_id = a.family_id
LEFT JOIN 
    my_table c ON c.parent_id = b.item_id AND c.family_id = b.family_id
LEFT JOIN 
    my_table d ON d.parent_id = c.item_id AND d.family_id = c.family_id
LEFT JOIN 
    my_table e ON e.parent_id = d.item_id AND e.family_id = d.family_id
LEFT JOIN 
    my_table f ON f.parent_id = e.item_id AND f.family_id = e.family_id
LEFT JOIN 
    my_table g ON g.parent_id = f.item_id AND g.family_id = f.family_id
LEFT JOIN 
    my_table h ON h.parent_id = g.item_id AND h.family_id = g.family_id
LEFT JOIN 
    my_table i ON i.parent_id = h.item_id AND i.family_id = h.family_id
WHERE 
    a.parent_id IS NULL;

  +-------------+
  | series      |
  +-------------+
  | 1,2,3,4,5,6 |
  | 1,2,3,7,8,9 |
  +-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I have questions about options #1 and #2: How does calling a stored procedure help with this? Is it because you can call it recursively? Also, could you please give a quick example of how to structure #2? And yes, just for the record, I ended up using option #4 to solve the problem. Still curious about #1 and #2 though. Thanks.

Comment: For 1. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750165/stored-procedure-with-recursive-call-using-mysql . For 2. See the definitive guide: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Great links. Thanks. #1 is in fact a recursive call with an SP, and #2 makes a lot of sense with the `parent_id` field. I've done similar stuff before, but in this case, #2 doesn't make too much sense. Still, very good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve the first problem.

Note that "set" is a keyword, so I renamed the first column to "sset"

You can see the result in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef6360/5

Create table and insert data:

```
create table test
(
    sset    int not null
    , item1 int not null
    , item2 int not null
) engine=InnoDB;

insert into test
values
(1, 1, 2)
, (1, 2, 3)
, (1, 3, 4)
, (1, 4, 5)
, (1, 5, 6)
```

Run the query:

```
select
    sset
    , group_concat(distinct item1or2 order by item1or2 asc)
from
    (
        select
            sset
            , item1 as item1or2
        from test
        union all
        select 
            sset
            , item2 as item1or2
        from test 
    ) u;
```

The output is:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: That only works if the numbers are in an order that is always correct when you use an `ORDER BY ASC` clause. Unfortunately, that may not always be the case with the actual data set I'm dealing with. I apologize for not mentioning that initially in my original post. I used the column name `set` and sequential numbers to make the question simpler and more generic, but that's unfortunately not the reality of the data. I will edit my question to reflect that. Sorry.